# Type mismatch: cannot convert from double[] to double

Tags: java, math

Maybe it is a beginner error, but I am disappointed by this error : 
Type mismatch: cannot convert from double[] to double

This is my code :

```
private double[][] valueRSSI = new double[5][10];
private double value;

[...]

for(int i=0;i<=M;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<=N;j++)
            {
                kNN[i][j]=0;
                for(int k=0;k<=(numberdisplay-1);k++)
                {
                    value = valueRSSI[k]; //The problem is here
                    kNN[i][j]=kNN[i][j]+ Math.pow( value - wifiActivity.getRadioMap(i,j,k),2) + value;
                }
            }
        }   

    }
```

All of the variables are double, double[] or [][]. I have googled this error, but I don't find quickly this problem. Eclipse ask me to change valueRSSI from double[] to double, but I need a table for this. How can I solve this error? Thank you.

Comment: Can you show the stacktrace + definition of `value` and `valueRSSI`?

Comment: It's hard to help you when we don't know which line is generating the problem, or which variable has which type. Please provide more information.

Comment: Based on the hint by eclipse, the error is not in the code you showed us. The only place where you use `valueRSSI` it is correct.

Comment: Indeed. You say "All of the variables are double, double[] or [][]," but it matters very much which is which! We need to see their declarations, and also we need to know precisely which line the compiler rejects.

Comment: How are `value` and `valueRSSI` declared?

Comment: @Heuster -- how do you know that? What if `valueRSSI` is double[][] ?

Comment: Ahs sorry, the line with a problem is value=valueRSSI[k]

Comment: Show the declaration of `valueRSSI`, please. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `value` is `double` but trying to assign `valueRSSI[k];` which is `double[]`.

you can do:`value=valueRSSI[k][j];`

Comment: I am a stupid guy ... how I didn't see that... Thank you.

Comment: Good to hear that.Then please check this question as answered.